# change sth in component if the route change in angular 2

Tags: angular, routes

in angular 2 it has an input in a header that exists on all pages. I want if the routing has changed the text in the input clear. The most important thing in the header is a selection input that when you select one of the options it prints in the input. So what should I do to delete that text when going to another page?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen to a route change event and clear your variable on change:

```
constructor ( private router: Router ) {
    router.events.subscribe ( event => {
        if( event instanceof NavigationEnd ){
            // clear input
        }
    } );
}
```

Also NavigationStart event is available: https://angular.io/api/router

Comment: thanks very much,I was really confused. But how can I make some exception for just two pages that the variable remains in the input?

Comment: in the event there is probably the page/route that you are navigating to or from, you could use this information eg: 
if (event.url === 'mypage') {
   /// clear input
}

Comment: where should I put this code: if (event.url === 'mypage') { /// clear input }? I have navigate method in onSelect function for selection in that input,when user chooses the option the page navigate to another page.

Comment: I was saying to put it in the if() { //here } that I pasted in above. Can you make a JS fiddle or something as I dont understand your question. It doesnt need to be functional, just to show your code

Comment: thank you Ben I understood and it worked, you are expert in this subject.